# Change Azure DevOps Projects to another project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, repo

I accidently pointed my VSCode project to a wrong DevOps Project, hence, wrong repository. How can I undo (maybe detach?) and point it back to my desired DevOps Project?

I'm using Git.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I didn't find the solution. I changed at Visual Studio (Team Explorer > Settings > Repository Settings > Remotes > Delete & Add Remote). So when I open my VSCode, it change accordingly but I'm getting error to commit such as 'no common commit' and more errors as I tried so I give up..

Answer (score 0):

> How can I undo (maybe detach?) and point it back to my desired DevOps Project?

First, to keep your code safe, you'd better backup your vscode project.

To point it back to the desired DevOps Project, we could connect the correct azure devops project repo in the VS code, then copy your VSCode project to the local folder of your correct repo, we could submit this new added project to the correct repo.

Undo the change in the worong devops project, we could delete that project manually if you clear all files you adeed. If you have installed the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension installed you should be able to simply select "Restore" action from selected "File history" commit.

Hope this helps.